# Ajax call to Azure function returns no data

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

It is my first time using Azure Functions. I am trying to access a 3rd party API with an auth token passed in the header. I have had some success getting data back when I run the Azure function alone locally in that it logs the correct data to my console. I have deployed this basic function to Azure, and added * to the CORS list for testing. However, when I created a simple HTML file to host on our website with ajax within a script tag to get this data - so that I may eventually display it on the html page - nothing is returned. I have not found any other examples using my specific code base or with code this simple. There are no error messages, it just logs ''. Here is my html/JS script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("fired off on ready...");
    var url = "https://{...}.azurewebsites.net/api/{...}?"
    
       $.ajax({
           method: "GET",
           url: url,
           crossDomain: true,
           success: function (respData) {
               console.log(respData);
                $("#functionData").html("<div style='padding: 5em 1em; text-align: center; color: #008800'>" + respData + "</div>");
           },
          error: function (jqXHR) {
              console.log(jqXHR)
              $("#functionData").html("<div style='padding: 1em; text-align: center; color: #660000'>Sorry, an error occurred: " + jqXHR.responseText + "</div>");
          }
       });
    })
</script>
```

And here is my index.js file in my Azure function:

```
module.exports = async function(context) {

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://{apiUrl}',
  headers: { 
    'auth-token': '{...}'
  }
};

await axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  let res = JSON.stringify(response.data)
  context.log(res);
  return res;
})
.catch(function (error) {
  context.log(error);
});

}
```

And just in case it's relevant, here is my function.json file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

As I said, the context.log displays data in my terminal in VSCode when I run the azure function locally, so I had been operating under the assumption that it is also returning the data - but now I am not sure.

Any guidance you can offer would be much appreciated, I feel like I must be really close, but some configuration is just not quite right. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

My function app code

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: '',
        headers: { }
        };
    try{
       
        var response= await axios(config)
        const data=JSON.stringify(response.data)               
        context.res = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: data
        }
    }catch(err){
        context.log(err)
        throw err
    }


}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>API</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
       
       
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (respData, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(respData)
                   
                    #process data and show data
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                }
            });
        
    });
  
    
});
</script>
</head>
 
<body>

  
<button id="submit">Call API</button>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Test
[image]